# How to find $\frac{0}{0}$ limit without L'Hôpital's rule

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I am having trouble solving this limit. I tried applying L'Hôpital's rule but I got $\frac{0}{0}$.

$$\lim_{x\to0} {\frac{\frac{1}{1+x^3} + \frac{1}{3}\log{\left(1+3x^3\right)}-1}{2\sin{\left(3x^2\right)}-3\arctan{\left(2x^2\right)}}}$$

I would appreciate any hints in the right direction. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Have you tried to use L'Hopital's rule more than one time ? Like iterating unless you get the result you are searching for ?

Comment: Yes I have tried twice, should I try even more??

Comment: I would try until I got a result and then maybe try with other methods

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $$\frac{1}{1+x^3} = 1 - x^{3} + x^{6} - x^{9} + O(x^{12}) \,\,\, \text{and} \,\,\, \log (1 + 3x^3) = 3x^3 - \frac{9x^6}{2} - 9x^9 + O(x^{12})$$

$$\sin (3x^2) = 3x^2  - \frac{9x^6}{2} + O(x^{10}) \,\,\, \text{and} \,\,\, \arctan (2x^2) = 2x^2 - \frac{8x^6}{3} + O(x^{10}) $$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: what is $O(x^{12})$?

Comment: Check [Big O notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation).

Comment: It means that there are terms omitted, terms that go to zero as $x\rightarrow 0$ at least as fast as $x^{12}$. It also implies that those terms are negligible compared to the terms not omitted.

Comment: @grdgfgr Not strictly faster, but at least as fast as $x^{12}$.

Comment: @Aaron Maroja, yes, I think I get your idea, really appreciate it.

Comment: @user244101 You're most welcome. Post your progress in your question, or you might want to answer your question. I know you're new here and people tend to be a little harsh. If this answer was really helpful, consider hitting the $\checkmark$. Take a look at this [thread](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/why-should-we-accept-answers).

Answer (score 1):

Recall some standard limits (which can be computed without using
l'Hospital's rule ):
\begin{eqnarray*}
\lim_{u\rightarrow 0}\frac{\frac{1}{1+u}-1+u}{u^{2}} &=&1 \\
\lim_{u\rightarrow 0}\frac{\log (1+u)-u}{u^{2}} &=&-\frac{1}{2} \\
\lim_{u\rightarrow 0}\frac{\sin u-u}{u^{3}} &=&-\frac{1}{6} \\
\lim_{u\rightarrow 0}\frac{\arctan u-u}{u^{3}} &=&-\frac{1}{3}.
\end{eqnarray*}
Now one can re-write the original expression using those of the standard
limits above as follows 
\begin{eqnarray*}
{\frac{\frac{1}{1+x^{3}}+\frac{1}{3}\log {\left( 1+3x^{3}\right) }-1}{2\sin {%
\left( 3x^{2}\right) }-3\arctan {\left( 2x^{2}\right) }}} &{=}&\frac{\left( 
\frac{1}{1+x^{3}}-1+x^{3}\right) +\left( \frac{1}{3}\log {\left(
1+3x^{3}\right) -x}^{3}\right) }{\left( 2\sin {\left( 3x^{2}\right) -6x}%
^{2}\right) -\left( 3\arctan {\left( 2x^{2}\right) -6x}^{2}\right) } \\
&=&\frac{\left( \frac{\frac{1}{1+(x^{3})}-1+(x^{3})}{(x^{3})^{2}}\right)
+3\times \left( \frac{\left( \log {\left( 1+\left( 3x^{3}\right) \right) -}%
\left( {3x}^{3}\right) \right) }{(3x^{3})^{2}}\right) }{2\times 3^{3}\left( 
\frac{\sin {\left( 3x^{2}\right) -(3x}^{2})}{(3x^{2})^{3}}\right) -3\times
2^{3}\left( \frac{\arctan {\left( 2x^{2}\right) -(2x}^{2})}{\left(
2x^{2}\right) ^{3}}\right) }
\end{eqnarray*}
It follows that 
\begin{equation*}
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\left( \frac{\frac{1}{1+x^{3}}+\frac{1}{3}\log {\left(
1+3x^{3}\right) }-1}{2\sin {\left( 3x^{2}\right) }-3\arctan {\left(
2x^{2}\right) }}\right) =\frac{\left( 1\right) +3\times \left( -\frac{1}{2}%
\right) }{2\times 3^{3}\left( -\frac{1}{6}\right) -3\times 2^{3}\left( -%
\frac{1}{3}\right) }=\frac{1}{2}.
\end{equation*}